# Classification Of $3x^2+4xy-6y^2-z=0$

Tags: analytic-geometry

> Classify the quadratic surface $3x^2+4xy-6y^2-z=0$

Looking at $$\begin{vmatrix}\lambda-3 & -2 & 0\\-2 & \lambda+6 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{vmatrix}=0$$

So how can I classify it?

Comment: Look at $\left(\frac{4}{2}\right)^2-3\times(-6)$, its [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant).

Comment: So it can not be love using this method ?

Answer (score 1):

First, as the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0&0\\2&-6&0&0\\0&0&0&\frac12\\0&0&\frac12&0\end{bmatrix}$$
has rank $4$, the quadric is non-degenerate.

Second, as the characteristic polynomial of the *quadratic form* is  $_\lambda(\lambda^2+3\lambda-22)$, the eigenvalues are $0$ and a positive and a negative eigenvalue (just look at the signs of the coefficients). The *signature* of the quadratic form is $(1,1)$ and its rank is $2$.

So we know  the quadric is either a hyperbolic paraboloid or a hyperbolic cylinder.

The former is correct, because the quadric has an equation of the form
$$z=\text{quadratic form in } x \text{ and } y \text{ alone.}$$

Indeed its equation can be written as
$$z=\frac12(3x+2y)^2-\frac{22}3y^2.$$